# How do you specify DST when scheduling a meeting in Outlook?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, time-zone

I am currently working in Europe (Central Europe Time time zone) and I want to schedule a meeting on October 31st 2021 at 02:30 with a colleague in Atlanta (Eastern time).  Unfortunately, on October 31st my time zone switches from summertime (CEST) to wintertime (CET).  This means that the clock is moved 1 hour backwards, and 02:30 is not uniquely defined.  In Outlook I can select the time zone of the meeting, but I cannot select whether it should be summertime (DST) or wintertime (no DST).

A somewhat similar problem happened on March 28th 2021.  Since DST starts on that day, 02:30 doesn't exist.  However, Outlook doesn't report a problem here.

Although my exist use case is slightly different, the main question remains: how does software correctly handle local times and DST switches in its user interface?

Comment: I believe that Windows itself maintains a list, updated regularly, of when various locations begin and end their clock changes (DST or Summer Time), so that when you set a time and zone for that time, someone in another zone will see the time automatically compensated for zone and clock changes.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin, that's not the point.  If I choose 2:30 at start moment for a meeting, I can select a time zone, but not whether it is summer- or wintertime (CEST or CET).  I can select the Europe/Amsterdam time zone, but I cannot select whether it is summer- or wintertime (02:30 summertime would be CEST, UTC+02:00 while 02:30 wintertime would be CET, UTC+01:00).  The Outlook dropdown only shows Europe/Amsterdam UTC+01:00 (which is actually wintertime, CET), but what if I want to schedule the meeting at 02:30 CEST (which is UTC+02:00).  I don't want to select e.g. Europe/Beirut (UTC+02:00).

Comment: Good article about time normalization in Outlook [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/troubleshoot/user-interface/how-time-zone-normalization-works-in-outlook). The easiest (maybe) would be to set the meeting time by selecting UTC time.

Comment: Actually, it _is_ the point: If you select a date and time, Outlook/Windows will know at that point whether DST/ST is in effect on that date, and will adjust accordingly - if you're in Amsterdam, it doesn't matter whether you're in Summer Time, you are in _Zone_ UTC+1, even if the _current_ clock adjustment is UTC+2.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin, I agree if this is about other moments (before or after October 31st), but October 31st 2021 02:30 is both in summer- and wintertime, but they are clearly 2 different moments.  How can Outlook know if DST is in effect at that time?  It's a kind of Schrodinger's case: it's both DST and non-DST and we only know it once the meeting starts.  How can my US colleague know when the meeting starts?

Comment: Windows maintains a list internally - generally as part of an update early in the year - of the dates when each country shifts to plus-one time or back to standard time. With that list, it becomes possible to correctly schedule up to about six months in advance with certainty, and very likely farther forward, as the dates that a given country shifts generally do not change every year. Since (by now) the 2021 plus-one data has been sent to all supported Windows systems, you can schedule a meeting for pretty much any time before the first shift of 2022, and the info will be correctly adjusted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have dealt with the simpler variant - people who send out notices for a "Standard Time" meeting before the time change for the first few weeks of "Daylight Saving Time", or for a "Daylight Saving Time" meeting before the time change for the first few weeks of "Standard Time". Confusion reigns supreme, even within a single physical time zone (e.g., US Eastern Time). Even before you get to the technical computer problems, far too many people don't understand. Really. Sadly.

What I recommend, any time there is potential confusion, is to include the desired information in the **text** of the meeting invitation. In addition, a separate followup email can be helpful.

Instead of the meeting title:

- November Budget Review

make it

- November Budget Review, 02:30 Central Europe Winter Time, UTC +1

If your primary contacts are in one specific time zone, include that as well:

- November Budget Review, Oct. 31, 02:30 Central Europe Winter Time, UTC +1, Atlanta Oct. 30, 21:30 Eastern Daylight Time

In this specific case, I would go with winter time rather than summer time, because summer time makes no sense after the first half hour.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to specify the time zone for every attendee of the meeting.

Outlook stores internally the meeting time in UTC, which is globally known,
and has no summer/winter times.

Outlook uses the time-zone of the user to calculate his meeting time automatically.

So all you have to do is create the meeting in your time-zone.
When the attendee enters the meeting in his calendar, the rest is automatic.

For detailed information see
[How time zone normalization works in Microsoft Outlook](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/troubleshoot/user-interface/how-time-zone-normalization-works-in-outlook).

Comment: Agree. Usually, "Outlook could normalize the time of the meeting based on the Windows global time zone database on the attendee's computer to determine the UTC time."

Comment: I agree that information should be stored in UTC.  But users don't work with UTC, they work in local time, and the conversion from local time to UTC can be ambiguous.  Let's assume we plan a meeting, and I want it to start on October 31st 2021, 02:30 (Europe/Amsterdam).  What is the UTC time point? (spoiler: there are 2).

Comment: The meeting time is converted to UTC according to your current time zone, and then stays immutable. As explained in the link, meeting time is always calculated as "UTC + Time zone + DST". So if the attendee's government decides to change the DST, then meeting time could move, and the same for the organizer. UTC keeps some stability here.

Comment: You are missing the point. October 31st 2021, 02:30 (Europe/Amsterdam) can be translated to UTC in two different ways: UCT + Europe/Amsterdam + 1h, and UCT + Europe/Amsterdam + 0h. Because 02:30 is an ambiguous moment.
UTC 00:30 translates to 02:30 in Amsterdam, but also UTC 01:30 translates to 02:30 in Amsterdam. This is because at 03:00 the clock is moved 1 hour backwards and 02:30 exists twice in this time zone. Outlook could guess of course, but this will be wrong in 50% of the cases. It means that there is a big chance that my US colleagues will be too early or too late for the meeting.

Comment: I'm not missing the point - *at the time that you created the event* there was only one UTC time that applied.

Comment: Ok, I see.  You mean that when in summertime, October 31st 2021, 02:30 should always be 02:30 summertime, so 00:30 UTC, and there is no way to plan a meeting at 02:30 wintertime (01:30 UTC).  To me it looks like a trick to bypass the ambiguity, but a pragmatic solution here might be sufficient.

Comment: Microsoft took the pragmatic way here, that of "UTC + Time zone + DST". Whenever DST changes for one, it might not change for others elsewhere, so UTC is the solution. One is advised to recheck the timing of international events, because they may move when DST changes for somebody.